# list view only updates after i have tapped on the list view

Tags: android

My listview only update if I drag it up or tapped it till its not getting update with new values.

```
public void additem(final String name,final String mess) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Messages v=new Messages();
            v.setName(name);
            v.setmessage(mess);
            PersonList.add(v); 
            mConversationArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mConversationView.invalidateViews();
            mConversationView.setSelection(mConversationArrayAdapter.getCount() - 1);

        }
    });

}


<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" 
        android:stackFromBottom="true">
</ListView>
```

Comment: can u add more code to understand

Comment: where u call this methed additem any buttan

Comment: does your List is common for adapter and addItem method ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the transcriptMode set.

android:transcriptMode

Sets the transcript mode for the list. In transcript mode, the list scrolls to the bottom to make new items visible when they are added.

Remove transcriptMode or set it to disabled as a solution for your problem.

Please Refere : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode